Something like Heroku but that does not restart/wipe server processes periodically, because I want to build a websocket game server in Node.js
I am looking for a PaaS that supports Node.js and a persistent in-memory game state. I don't want the state of the game to reset randomly during gameplay.
And, by the way, I am totally fine with the app resetting/restarting on deploy, e.g., when I push changes to the repository. It's for a hobby project, I don't really need advanced DevOps features.
I wish I could use Heroku itself, but the only way that I know would work would be by using Redis and I am afraid the latency would be unacceptable for the kind of game that I want to develop.
